# How to know what is the real content type of the part in multipart request

Tags: java, http-post, mime-types, multipartform-data, multipart

I am sending a multipart request from my client to my server like this:

```
FileBody file2 = new FileBody(new File("./test2.txt"));
FileBody image1 = new FileBody(new File("./DSC_0064.JPG"));
```

and as you see, one of the files is txt, and one if JPG image.

On the server, I receive the request and I take the headers for each part, and I get this:

```
------------Part 1------------
content-disposition=form-data; name="test2"; filename="test2.txt"
content-type=application/octet-stream
content-transfer-encoding=binary
------------Part 2------------
content-disposition=form-data; name="image1"; filename="DSC_0064.JPG"
content-type=application/octet-stream
content-transfer-encoding=binary
```

As you see, the content type for both of them is `application/octet-stream`. How to determine in the dynamic environment the actual type? Is it an image? a text? a video?

I can't depend on the file name because the user can change it for example from txt to png and then my server will think that it is an image but he will exception because of that.

Comment: There's not really a way to find out. File extensions are meant for that purpose exactly. After a file is in bytes, it can be text, compressed data, images, songs, etc. What you can do is to catch the error and disregard that file. You can do this in the client side even, so the server doesn't get a lot of trash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are not setting a MIME type. You can the other constructor [`FileBody(file, contentType)`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/FileBody.html#FileBody%28java.io.File,%20org.apache.http.entity.ContentType%29) that takes a content type:

```
FileBody file2 = new FileBody(new File("./test2.txt"), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
FileBody image1 = new FileBody(new File("./DSC_0064.JPG"), ContentType.create("image/jpeg"));
```

Comment: let me test u and come back

Comment: wait please, in the `create` method, maybe the client write anything?? like `ContentType.create("no longer mime type")` ??